# Tensorflow (steps, batch_size and periods)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, training-data

I am a little confused while training a model in tensorflow. What are steps and batch_size and periods in the train_model function? The code for the train_model function is given [in the link to Learn from google AI](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/synthetic_features_and_outliers.ipynb?hl=en#scrollTo=VgQPftrpHbG3)

Comment: You should expand on your question and add reference to the function.

Comment: how about now? sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of `steps`, as described in the method's comment, is the number of forward and backward passes on a batch. 
The size of this batch (`batch_size`) is the number of training samples used for this training pass. You are approximating the loss, and therefore the gradient of your whole dataset by just computing it over `batch_size` samples. This basic terminology is explained in many introductory courses to neural networks.

The loop over the `period` variable here is just used to display some loss metrics once in a while.